# Stroking UIImage in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

No Stroke:

[image: No stroke]

Stroke:

[image: Stroked]

Is it possible to do this kind of effect with CoreImage or any other third party framework?

I tried overlapping images to make the illusion of stroking but it is not even through all the shape

Comment: As odd an answer as it might seem since you don't literally want a shadow, have you tried setting the an image view's layer's `shadowRadius` (to something large), `shadowOpacity` (to `1.0`, probably) and `shadowColor` (to orange)? If you don't also set a `shadowPath` then the shadow is computed on the GPU from the original pixel contents of the layer. Adding a stroke to the layer, as far as I'm aware, requires you to specify geometry.

Comment: Maybe use a [CILineOverlay](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CILineOverlay) filter to get the outline, followed by a color adjustment filter to make it orange (CIColorCube maybe, or CIColorMap). Then overlay your original image on top of the orange outline to get the final result.